# How do i get the value in the textfield in GUI? java

Tags: java, swing

I also wanted to make the input dynamic so that it changes the value as i press any key. Thanks i dont know how to use a keylistener or something that would process my code.

```
public static void DecimalToAll(String varInput){
    //DeciToHexa
    int varDeciToHexa = Integer.parseInt(varInput);
    String DeciToHexaAnswer = Integer.toHexString(varDeciToHexa);
    System.out.println(DeciToHexaAnswer.toUpperCase());
    //DeciToOctal
    int varDeciToOctal = Integer.parseInt(varInput);
    String DeciToOctalAnswer = Integer.toOctalString(varDeciToOctal);
    System.out.println(DeciToOctalAnswer);
    //DeciToBinary
    int varDeciToBinary = Integer.parseInt(varInput);
    String DeciToBinaryAnswer = Integer.toBinaryString(varDeciToBinary);
    System.out.println(DeciToBinaryAnswer);
```

Comment: myInputField.getText() ?

Comment: How can i monitor it so that whenever it changes value, my program would automatically process it. I'm using buttons in GUI.

Comment: what happens in your method, stays in your method. those variables won't even exist until the method is called. Seeing that you show nothing of your other code, nor state what exactly it is you are trying to do, all I can guess now is: when you run the method (on clicking the button, I suppose) pas a parsed version of the result of getText as parameter to the method

Comment: how would i trigger an event that upon changing the value in the textfield, it would call the method again. Thanks for answering

Comment: add a listener to the textfield to do so.

Comment: What kind of listener can do that? I mean any hint will do

Comment: @PatrickGomez Take a look at my solution below.

Comment: ValueChangeListener , for instance... but really, have you tried to google this?

Comment: I did but I'm getting too bloated with all the codes in Netbeans.

Comment: First learn to develop basic code, then start using IDE's. Especially if you get "too bloated", take a step back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**An example making use of DocumentListener:**

[image]

---

JTextField can't add a "ChangeListener" like other components. To "monitor' changes in a `JTextField`, you can add a ***DocumentListener*** to the textfield:

```
private class MyDocumentListener implements DocumentListener
{
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e){
        //Do nothing
    }
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e){
        //Do things when text are inserted
    }
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e){
        //Do things when text are deleted
    }
}
```

To add the ***DocumentListener***, get the `Document` object from `JTextField` and add it:

```
JTextField txt = new JTextFeld();
txt.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new MyDocumentListener());
```